# How can one use one Webform element's selection as the argument in an Entity Select element using Views

Tags: webforms, 9

I am hoping to use the selected option of one Webform element ("Organization") as the argument in an Entity Select element ("Site") using Views handler.

```
organization:
  '#type': entity_select
  '#title': 'What is the name of your organization?'
  '#empty_option': 'Please select'
  '#target_type': node
  '#selection_handler': 'default:node'
  '#selection_settings':
    target_bundles:
      organizations: organizations
site:
  '#type': entity_select
  '#title': Site
  '#target_type': node
  '#selection_handler': views
  '#selection_settings':
    view:
      view_name: sites
      display_name: entity_reference_1
      arguments:
        - 'WHAT DO I PUT HERE TO REPRESENT ORGANIZATION?'
```

I wouldn't expect this to happen with tokens, which become available after submission, but I was thinking this could potentially be done using "data", which is available to Webform Computed Twig elements. I tried adding `'#ajax': true` to the Entity Select element and then putting `{{ data.organization }}` as the argument, but that didn't work.

Thank in advance for any tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my colleague, @nikathone, provided the following code, to be put in a .module file. Replace the MYMODULE and MY_WEBFORM_ID according to your needs:

```
<?php

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\webform\Element\WebformEntitySelect;

/**
 * Implements hook_webform_submission_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_webform_submission_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $webform_id = $form['#webform_id'] ?? '';
  if ($webform_id !== 'MY_WEBFORM_ID') {
    return;
  }

  $organization_element = $form['elements']['organization'] ?? [];
  $site_element = $form['elements']['site'] ?? [];
  if (!$organization_element || !$site_element || empty($site_element['#selection_settings']['view'])) {
    return;
  }

  // Settings ajax related properties.
  $site_element_wrapper_id = $site_element['#webform_id'] . '--wrapper';
  $organization_element['#ajax'] = [
    'callback' => 'MYMODULE_webform_submission_form_organization_element_ajax_callback',
    'wrapper' => $site_element_wrapper_id,
  ];
  $site_element['#prefix'] = '<div id="' . $site_element_wrapper_id . '">';
  $site_element['#suffix'] = '</div>';

  // Attempting to retrieve possible selected organization.
  if (!($selected_organization = $form_state->getValue('organization'))) {
    $selected_organization = $organization_element['#default_value'] ?? 0;
  }
  // Apply the selected organization if a selected one was found.
  if ($selected_organization) {
    $site_element['#selection_settings']['view']['arguments'] = [$selected_organization];
    // Reset the options so that we can repopulate it again. Without this the
    // ::setOptions method above won't process the new arguments.
    $site_element['#options'] = [];
    $form_object = $form_state->getFormObject();
    $settings = ['webform_submission' => $form_object->getEntity()];
    WebformEntitySelect::setOptions($site_element, $settings);
  }

  $form['elements']['organization'] = $organization_element;
  $form['elements']['site'] = $site_element;
}

/**
 * Ajax callback for the site element.
 *
 * @param array $form
 *   The full form element.
 * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
 *   The form state.
 *
 * @return array
 *   The site element array.
 */
function MYMODULE_webform_submission_form_organization_element_ajax_callback(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  return $form['elements']['site'];
}
```